# finding time interval using time and date variables

Tags: r, date, time

I have multiple date variables that are in the following format (`"01-Jan-2010"`), pretty much `%d-%b-%Y` and I also have multiple time variables which are in military format.

So for event 1, there are date1 and time1, for event 2, there are date2 and time2.

How can I get the time difference between the events in minutes in R?

Thanks in advance

```
event1 event1_time  event1_date event2 event2_time event_2date
1        14:13        2014-10-10   1     15:34         2014-10-11
1        16:15        2011-02-01   1     18:22         2011-02-02
```

Comment: Please include representative & minimal sample data, e.g. using `dput`. I'm not sure what you're asking and what you expect as output. I am also not familiar with the term "military format".

Comment: the military format is 24hr format like in 18:37, 15:51

Comment: And your minimal & reproducible sample data?

Comment: I have the data at my work. I tried to edit my question. I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an option

```
# Define a function to parse the `date` and `time` strings
to_dt <- function(date, time)
    strptime(sprintf("%s %s", date, time), format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")

transform(
    df,
    diff = difftime(
        to_dt(event_2date, event2_time),
        to_dt(event1_date, event1_time),
        units = "mins"))
#  event1 event1_time event1_date event2 event2_time event_2date      diff
#1      1       14:13  2014-10-10      1       15:34  2014-10-11 1521 mins
#2      1       16:15  2011-02-01      1       18:22  2011-02-02 1567 mins
```

Or the same in `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    mutate(diff = difftime(
        to_dt(event_2date, event2_time),
        to_dt(event1_date, event1_time),
        units = "mins"))
```

If you would like the difference in another unit (e.g. days), you can use `units = "days"` inside `difftime` (take a look at `?difftime` to see more options).

---

### Sample data

```
df <- read.table(text =
    "event1 event1_time  event1_date event2 event2_time event_2date
1        14:13        2014-10-10   1     15:34         2014-10-11
1        16:15        2011-02-01   1     18:22         2011-02-02", header = T)
```

Comment: Thank for your help. I  appreciate it.

Comment: You're very welcome @CyberSpear. There's no need to say thank you here on Stack Overflow (those kind of comments usually get deleted by the mods after a while ;-). Instead you should consider closing the question by setting the green checkmark next to the answer. That way you help keeping SO tidy and make it easier for others to identify relevant questions. It also provides a small reputation bonus to both the original question poster and answerer.

Comment: using the same code, how can you get the average time. I tried psych:: describe, favstats and skim and all that I am getting are errors?

Comment: @CyberSpear I'm not sure I understand what you're asking. Best to ask a new question with some sample data and your expected output.